# What might the hash symbol (#) in this case URL be?

Tags: javascript, html, url

I know hash symbol (`#`) at the end of the URL represents fragment.
Like this:

```
https://example.com/path/file#id
```

But what if the hash symbol is placed in the middle of the URL path?
Like this:

```
https://example.com/path#/file
```

Does this hash symbol mean anything?

Comment: It's the same thing. The fragment is `/file`

Comment: Did you think there was some reason the fragment can't contain a `/` character?

Comment: @Barmar Yes. Why there is a `/` character in this fragment? Some URLs has more than 2 `/` characters. Like this: `https://example.com/path1#/path2/file`

Comment: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling This hash starts a hash URL part, that can contain forward slashes. There are navigation-related use cases of such (see the link). What's the problem?

Comment: `Why there is a / character in this fragment?` because there is, and furthermore, it's allowed to be there

Answer (score 1):

For websites designed as single-page applications or relying extensively on **AJAX** for seamless content loading without refreshing the page,
the #hash here is to convey and manage the application's state on the client side.
This mechanism allows the application itself,both the client and the browser to comprehend and handle the state.

U can read more about that

**https://www.quora.com/Is-AJAX-necessary-for-creating-dynamic-websites-or-could-it-be-replaced-with-alternative-technologies**

Answer (score 0):

In a URL, the hash symbol (#) is typically used to represent a fragment identifier, indicating a specific section within the document referred to by the URL. When the hash symbol is at the end of the URL, as in your first example (https://example.com/path/file#id), it indicates that the browser should scroll to and display the element with the ID "id" within the document.

However, when the hash symbol is placed in the middle of the URL path, as in your second example (https://example.com/path#/file), it doesn't have the same conventional meaning as a fragment identifier. In this case, the interpretation of the URL may depend on the specific web application or website handling the URL.

Some web applications use client-side routing, where the hash symbol is employed to manage navigation within a single page without triggering a full page reload. The portion of the URL after the hash symbol is then processed by JavaScript on the client side to determine what content to display. This is often seen in single-page applications (SPAs).

In your example (https://example.com/path#/file), it's possible that the web application at "https://example.com/path" is using client-side routing and will handle the "/file" portion of the URL to display the corresponding content on the page without requesting a new page from the server.

To understand the specific behavior in the context of the website you're working with, you would need to refer to the documentation or inspect the website's source code to see how it handles URLs with a hash symbol in the middle of the path.